# Ocaml operators in anonymous functions

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to write a function that will parse a list and create a new list that contains the words I want in this case names.

I can writ the function for one name e.g

```
let extract_name (lst : string list) : string list =
List.filter (fun x -> x = "George" ) (lst)
```

When I try and write it for more than one  name I get errors. I rearranged the parentheses a few times but I still get errors.

```
 let extract_name (lst : string list) : string list =
List.filter (fun x -> x = ("George" || "Victoria")) (lst)
```

Errors

```
 let extract_name (lst : string list) : string list =
 List.filter (fun x -> x = "George" || "Victoria") (lst)
 ;; 
 Characters 93-103:
 List.filter (fun x -> x = "George" || "Victoria") (lst)
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expecte of type bool
# let extract_name (lst : string list) : string list =
List.filter (fun x -> x = ("George" || "Victoria")) (lst);;
Characters 82-90:
List.filter (fun x -> x = ("George" || "Victoria")) (lst);;
                           ^^^^^^^^
Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected     of type bool
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to apply the boolean `||` operator on two strings here, which doesn't work and causes the type error. You need to test the equality with `x` for both strings separately, and then OR the result:

```
List.filter (fun x -> (x = "George") || (x = "Victoria")) lst
```

Comment: what if you want to compare it to the values in a list?

Comment: Then use something like [`fun x -> List.mem x ["George", "Victoria"]`](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/List.html#VALmem)